# MacOS VulkanInfo Reports 0 Validation Layers

Tags: macos, vulkan

I am getting started with Vulkan (vulkansdk-macos-1.1.126.0) on macOS (10.14.6), and have followed a tutorial in setting up an instance which all seems to go well however when I call `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` I get a returned layer count of 0.

At first I thought it could be my build arguments/variables, however when I run the vulkanInfo application supplied with the tar.gz it also reports there that there are no layers (`Layers: count = 0`). I then tried to add environment variables:

```
PATH=$PATH:$VULKAN_ROOT/bin
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_ROOT/etc/vulkan/explicit_layers.d
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=$VULKAN_ROOT/etc/vulkan/icd.d/MoltenVK_icd.json
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_ROOT/etc/vulkan/explicit_layers.d
export VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation vulkaninfo
#export VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation vulkaninfo
```

and launch vulkanInfo from the terminal. Maybe it is a Mac trying to be too secure issue or has something to do with file permissions. Any suggestions are appreciated since this will seriously hamper debugging.

Answer (score 1):

So as you'd expect I was doing something wrong, just doing 2 different things wrong:
- for launching vulkanInfo from the terminal, you can see that I wasn't exporting the `PATH` variable.
- for VSCode (where I am building the application) I had the `VK_ICD_FILENAMES` and `VK_LAYER_PATH` as preprocessor definitions, not as launch environment variables (set in the launch.json, environment name/value map).